# aws-sdk Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'region') in react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm importing the following in my react app

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk');
```

upon onSuccess in `authenticateUser` i'm getting the following error

```
onSignInFailure: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')
    at Object.onSuccess (authenticate.ts?c0c4:55:1)
    at CognitoUser.authenticateUserInternal (CognitoUser.js?3c43:470:1)
    at eval (CognitoUser.js?3c43:333:1)
    at eval (CognitoUser.js?3c43:312:1)
    at eval (Client.js?1610:140:1)
```

My code

```
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import Pool from "./UserPool";
const AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk');

const authenticate = async (Username, Password) => (
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = new CognitoUser({ Username, Pool });
      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({ Username, Password });

      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: data => {
          console.log('onSuccess:', data);
          // AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
          AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

          AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', // your identity pool id here
            Logins: {
              // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
              'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx': data
                .getIdToken()
                .getJwtToken(),
            },
          });
          console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
          

          //refreshes credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()
          AWS.config.credentials.refresh(error => {
            if (error) {
              console.error('refresh err: ',error);
            } else {
              // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
              // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();
              console.log('Successfully logged!');
            }
          });
          
          resolve(data);
        },

        onFailure: err => {
          console.error('onSignInFailure:', err);
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    })
)
```